# Linear regression model drop1 function in r

Tags: r, regression

I'm experiencing problems with drop1 function output for linear regression models. It shows me F test results for an interaction term, but only shows one value of degree of freedom not two. I'm confused why there are not 2 df...

Here is one example output:--if I used "Chisq" then output shows even fewer things...

[image: I was expecting NumDF and DenDF]

Here is another output from a different model that I can get two DFs (the only issue is with lm; lmer works fine for me)--doesn't matter whether I used "F" or "Chisq", output is the same

[image]

Does anyone know what problem this is, and how I can get two DFs for a lm model in drop1 function? Thank you!!

Comment: FYI - You should include separate (single d.f.) for the "main effects" of condition, age group, and gender in the model along with the interaction term.   If an interaction term is only giving 1 d.f. it usually means that the variables whose values are multiplied together, i.e., for your three-way interaction $X_1*X_2*X_3$, are being treated as continuous and not categorical.  Isn't there a "factor" command to tell R that a variable is categorical in a regression model?

Comment: Hi there! I checked my code and confirmed that the variables are factor variables, so they shouldn't be treated as continuous? I still do not know how to get both NumDF and DenDF though...thanks!

Comment: It looks like the product Condition * AgeGroup * Gender is being treated like all three are continuous like Age * Weight * BloodPressure --> which will always give 1 d.f.  So look up how to code interactions for categorical (factor-type) variables in regression models for R.

Comment: It looks like R users are generating dummy variables (0,1) for categorical interaction terms in R.   See https://daviddalpiaz.github.io/appliedstats/categorical-predictors-and-interactions.html   and   https://www.r-bloggers.com/interpreting-interaction-coefficient-in-r-part1-lm/